# Converting XYZ file to shapefile using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, convert, xyz

I have numerous XYZ files, which aren't gridded and I'd like to use Python to convert them to shapefiles.

I'm not quite sure how to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have numerous XYZ files, which aren't gridded

from [GDAL XYZ – ASCII Gridded XYZ](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/xyz.html)

> GDAL supports reading and writing ASCII gridded XYZ raster datasets (i.e. **ungridded XYZ, LIDAR XYZ etc. must be opened by other means**

The ungridded XYZ file header

```
# test.xyz
#
0.3517846     -0.7869986      -2.873479    
0.5057634     -0.7079139      -2.871073    
0.6422613     -0.5988617      -2.868600    
.....
```

Read the xyz file with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
inputfile = "test.xyz"
df  = pd.read_table(inputfile, skiprows=2, delim_whitespace=True, names=['x', 'y', 'z'])
print(df.head(3))
      x         y         z
0  0.351785 -0.786999 -2.873479
1  0.505763 -0.707914 -2.871073
2  0.642261 -0.598862 -2.868600
```

Convert the pandas DataFrame to a 2D [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) GeoDataFrame

```py
import geopandas as gpd
gdf2d = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.x, df.y))
print(gdf2d.head(3))
      x         y         z                  geometry
0  0.351785 -0.786999 -2.873479  POINT (0.35178 -0.78700)
1  0.505763 -0.707914 -2.871073  POINT (0.50576 -0.70791)
2  0.642261 -0.598862 -2.868600  POINT (0.64226 -0.59886)
# to shapefile
gdf2d.to_file("test2d.shp")
```

Convert the pandas DataFrame to a 3D [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) GeoDataFrame

```py
 from shapely.geometry import Point
 gdf3d = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df.apply(lambda row: Point(row.x,row.y,row.z), axis=1))
 print(gdf3d.head(3))
       x         y         z                             geometry
 0  0.351785 -0.786999 -2.873479  POINT Z (0.35178 -0.78700 -2.87348)
 1  0.505763 -0.707914 -2.871073  POINT Z (0.50576 -0.70791 -2.87107)
 2  0.642261 -0.598862 -2.868600  POINT Z (0.64226 -0.59886 -2.86860)
 # to shapefile
 gdf3d.to_file("test3d.shp")
```

Comment: So interesting, pandas is low case, but GeoPandas is Camel case :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it seems to me that but in Qgis Processing / SAGA, the command 'import feature from XYZ' allows to generate shp